# Can you get the benefit of Saving Inspiration without spending a healing surge?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Warlord feat Saving Inspiration reads as follows:

> Benefit: When you use inspiring word, you can forgo any extra dice of
>   healing granted by the power to instead grant the target a saving
>   throw.

If a warlord uses Inspiring Word with this power, can the target choose not to make spend a healing surge but still make a saving throw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

If they don't spend a surge, they don't get the extra healing. If they wouldn't get the extra healing, they can't take the save instead if the extra healing.

On a side note, Mark of Healing (from the Eberron Player's Guide) is *vastly* superior to Saving Inspiration if you can take it.